# Free shipping counter that takes discount code into consideration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a free shipping counter in my woocommerce shop. It is realized with following code:

```
// free shipping counter
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'ml_free_shipping_cart_notice' );
  
function ml_free_shipping_cart_notice() {
  
   $min_amount = 150; //change this to your free shipping threshold
   
   $current = WC()->cart->subtotal;
  
   if ( $current < $min_amount ) {
      $added_text = 'Do darmowej przesyłki brakuje jeszcze ' . wc_price( $min_amount - $current ) . '!';
      $return_to = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
      $notice = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( $return_to ), 'Kontynuuj zakupy', $added_text );
      wc_print_notice( $notice, 'notice' );
   }
  
}



// ************************************************************************************




// free shipping info after 150pln
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'free_shipping_info' );
  
function free_shipping_info() {
  
   $min_amount = 150; //change this to your free shipping threshold
   
   $current = WC()->cart->subtotal;
  
   if ( $current >= $min_amount ) {
      $added_text = 'Przekroczyłeś 150zł! Twoje zamówienie wyślemy za darmo! :) Wybierz dowolny sposób wysyłki!';
      $return_to = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
      $notice = sprintf( $added_text );
      wc_print_notice( $notice, 'notice' );
   }
  
}
```

First part shows counter on the cart page - if cart amount is lower than 150pln it will show how much customer needs to spend to get free shipping. If customer exceed 150pln, second part of the code steps in saying that shipping is free now.

But there is a problem if customer uses discount code.
Example, like on the attached screen
[image]

1. total amount in the cart = 164,68pln, so free shipping is granted.
2. customer adds 15% discount code, so total is now 139,98pln and in such case shipping is not free yet.
   In such case counter should again show how much (s)he needs to spend to get free shipping.

I guess it's petty simple but have no idea how to modify the code to work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To always use the cart subtotal including taxes and discounts add the following function:

```php
// Utility function: Get cart subtotal including taxes and discounts
function cart_subtotal_incl_tax_with_discount() {
    return (float) WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total() + WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_tax();
}
```

And replace, in your code, both `WC()->cart->subtotal` with: 
 `cart_subtotal_incl_tax_with_discount()`